# heuristic for a directed random graph with positive weight edges

Tags: algorithm

I want to implement the A* algorithm and I have read about the heuristic function and how it works and I understand that an underestimate is needed to obtain an optimal path . But what heuristic function is the most suited for a random directed graph ? What I have tried so far is is taking the smallest edge weight from a node to the goal. As clearly the distance from a current node to the goal is not smaller than the smallest edge from a current node to the next.

Answer (score 2):

The Manhattan distance only works when you have a well-defined distance metric that you can apply to pairs of nodes, such as with points in a 2D plane.  For a graph, there's no inherent way to get the distance between two nodes.

With the little information available to you from the problem definition, I don't think you will do much better than using the heuristic that assumes all unseen edges have weight equal to the smallest weight in the graph.

You could get a bit more advanced if you sorted all the edges by weight.  Then, as you see edges with particular weights during A*, you can remove them from the sorted list.  This will let you know a running value of what the smallest remaining edge weight could be.